# Distinguishing which parameters belong to which object

Tags: php

This is a pretty specific problem, which I can't find an answer for anywhere.
This applies to lots of languages but I'm particularly wanting to figure it out in PHP.
For the sake of this I'll be using 'events' as our classes. Keeping it simple there are 2 types:

```
abstract class Event{
    protected $cost;
    protected $startTime;

    public function __construct(){
        foreach($eventData as $key => $val){
            if(property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class Party extends Event{
    private $hasPointyHats;

    public function __construct($eventData){
        parent::__construct($eventData);
        $this->hasPointyHats = $eventData->hasPointyHats;
    }
}
```

Class Event has 2 props: cost and startTime. When it is constructed, it should be passed an associative array containing all of the parameters of the event, and it'll automatically set the property to the passed array value.

Class Party extends Event by establishing whether or not this event will have those awesome pointy party hats (I'm not going if it doesn't).

And no. No it doesn't. Because when you pass this object:

```
//Some result set...
$mysqli_result = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

which has cost, startTime, and hasPointyHats values (possibly even more!), you get the following little error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Party::$hasPointyHats in C:\somePath\Event.php on line 35
```

I understand why. Because in "Event", $this refers to the "party" object but it's private.
I am not looking to overwrite every property in the object in the super constructor, just the ones that belong to the super class (abstract class Event) itself. Is there a way to target the specific properties of the Event class and NOT the ones of the child class? That way, no matter what object I extend it with, I wont end up accidentally setting properties on the child class because the passed object had some conflicting property?

I assume it's some silly easy thing like super->property or whatever, but I need to still be able to use property_exists with it.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property_exists with just a class name instead of an object.
Like this:

```
abstract class Event{
protected $cost;
protected $startTime;

public function __construct($eventData){
    foreach($eventData as $key => $val){
        if(property_exists(__CLASS__, $key)){
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I actually like this better than my own answer. I guess I didn't double-check the property_exists() docs closely enough.

Comment: I swear to you that this came to me at 1:45 AM last night as I was falling asleep. I even read it in the DOCs and for whatever reason I was overthinking it. This is absolutely the answer **DUH**. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) specifically states in the documentation that as of PHP 5.3, it checks the existence of a property **independent of accessibility**, which explains the behaviour you're seeing.

[`get_object_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), on the other hand, gets a list of the defined properties **in scope**, so should work better for your purposes.

Try something like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $props = get_object_vars($this);
    foreach ($eventData as $key => $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $props)) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't specifically check that it's a property of the parent class, just that it's accessible from the parent class.

If you really want to restrict to just the parent class, [`get_class_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) might be even better:

```
public function __construct() {
    $props = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);
    foreach ($eventData as $key => $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $props)) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```